# Java Program to convert PDF To HTML?

Tags: java, html, pdf

How can i write a Java code which will convert **PDF** file to **HTML**.If we have tables in **PDF** document the same table will be also in the **HTML** file same to other thing like color,link etc.

Comment: Given PDF is intended to be WYSIWYG & HTML is intended to adapt to the user device/preferences, most 'conversion' between PDF and HTML are atrocious.

Comment: I don't know why this has been voted down. It's not an easy thing to do and it requires heuristics. But I am doing precisely that.

Answer (score 2):

It's a two step process, because there's nothing that will read your mind:

1. Load the PDF into memory and parse the content using a library like iText.
2. Add the content to markup and output the HTML.

Only you can decide what the markup should be and what content should be displayed.  There's no standard, and no software can read your mind.

Why can't you just stream the PDF to the browser and display it that way?  No need for HTML.

Comment: We have to store the content in DB and then show in JSF page

Comment: So?  Store a blob and get on with it.

Comment: No we have to convert them in HTML then we will store in DB

Answer (score 2):

I am doing exactly this, based on Apache [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) (which is Java). See https://bitbucket.org/petermr/pdf2svg for conversion to SVG and https://bitbucket.org/petermr/svg2xml-dev to convert to XML. I shall be tackling tables in the next week.

The process is at least two steps and involves :

- convert PDF to SVG characters with font, size, x/y, etc. (PDFBox does this)
- use coordinates to find rectangular areas of the page.
- look for textual heuristics such as "table 1"
- attempt to interpret the areas as cells of rectangular tables

We then have to see if the table has regular columns and see if these have labels that make some sense.

Comment: are you converting it into HTML Also

Comment: Yes we have created a first cut at HTML which does running text, including superscipts, etc  well but we have to use heuristics for structuring the sections